# How to use Parse API to search user and add user as PFRelation?

Tags: ios, xcode, parse-platform, swift, uialertcontroller

I want that when a button is tapped, a UIAlertView pops up and provide a textField for the user to type the user that he wants to add. The process involves searching the EXACT username on Parse.com and add the user to the currentUser's PFRelation.

Here is the code in Swift.

```
@IBAction func addFriend(sender : AnyObject) {

    var currentUser = PFUser.currentUser()

    var alert = UIAlertController(title: "Add Friend", message: "Pleae enter a username.", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
    alert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler({(textField: UITextField!) in
        textField.placeholder = "Username"
        textField.secureTextEntry = false

        // Add button actions here
        var addBtnAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Add", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
            UIAlertAction in

            var text : String = textField.text

            println("I want to add the user: \(text)")

            var query = PFUser.query()
            query.whereKey("username", equalTo: text)
            query.getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock {
                (object: PFObject!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
                if !object {
                    NSLog("The getFirstObject request failed.")
                    //add alertView here later

                } else {
                    // The find succeeded.
                    NSLog("Successfully retrieved the object.")
                    //This can find username successfully

                    var friendsRelation : PFRelation = currentUser.relationForKey("friendsRelation")
                    var user : PFUser = text  // <<<<---- This is the line that has problem
// Xcode tells me that I cannot express a String as a PFUser
// How can I add the user that has the exact same username?  

                }
            }
        }

        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
        alert.addAction(addBtnAction)
        self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

        })
}
```

Thanks a lot for reading this. Please help me out!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you should do something like:

```
friendsRelation.addObject(object);
```

where `object` is the `PFUser` that you have previously queried for.

Comment: Thanks! How do I convert the string to a PFUser? I have no idea!

Comment: sorry, it is not clear to me what you are trying to do. `object` is already a `PFUser`, as per the callback signature… you cannot convert a string into a PFUser, you can signup a new user, and this will create, both locally and remotely a new `PFUser`…. hope this helps...

Comment: Hi. I want that when the user enters a username, Parse.com will find the user and add PFRelation of it to the user. The way to add a PFUser is to call friendsRelation.addObject(user). However, I have no idea how to find a PFUser with same user name as the string entered in textField. I understand that (user) has to be PFUser, but how do I find a PFUser with same name as the string? Or I should ask, how do I get the PFUser that I have queried for? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realise the returned value is object. Now my problem is solved. Thanks a lot!!